# Distinct Results from Solr Query

Tags: solr

I have the solr indexed data as below

```
<doc>
  <str name="pincode">792056</str>
  <str name="city">Bijoypur-I Bl.I -III</str>
  <str name="district">Changlang</str>
  <str name="locality">Bijoypur-I Bl.I -III</str>
  <str name="state">Arunachal Pradesh</str>
</doc>
```

My problem is for 10 distinct pincodes from the same state i have 10 documents and when i query for the states using the query `http://ip:port/solr/select?q=state:Arunachal Pradesh`
it returns 10 values with the same state name, But i need the distinct values of state name only, Please help me on this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check [grouping/field collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) feature in SOLR

```
&q=solr+memory&group=true&group.field=manu_exact
```

Comment: Thanks, yes grouping is what i am exactly looking for

Answer (score 5):

Is a facet query what you're after? This should get you a list of states with the number of docs per state:

```
http://ip:port/solr/select?q=*:*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.limit=-1&facet.field=state
```

Maybe describe exactly what the desired result is.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried the facet it is working but actually what i need is grouping